# ec2 persistent spot instance not restarting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This post on the AWS blog "[Amazon EC2 Spot Can Now Stop and Start Your Spot Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-ec2-spot-can-now-stop-and-start-your-spot-instances/)" describes that outbid spot instances can be restarted instead of recreated.

When I create a spot request using 'Request type: Request and Maintain' and 'Interruption behavior: stop', my instances stop when they are outbid and then instead of restarting, a new instance is created. I recall that in one test I saw the behavior that I am now expecting, but am not sure what I did differently to achieve that.

Can anyone clarify how to implement my desired behavior?

Comment: Have you selected multiple instance types or availability zones for the spot request?  Is the next instance of a different type or in a different AZ relative to the one before it?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work right now with one instance and "Availability Zone: no preference". Trying the simplest config to get it working correctly. Aside from Request type and Interruption behavior, I'm only setting AMI, Instance type, Maximum price, User data, Instance tags ("test"), Key pair name and Security groups. None of those would affect that type of behavior I'm hoping.

Comment: I admit, I'm guessing, but you might want to specify a single AZ, also, since otherwise the service could potentially give you a new one in a different zone.